# PDFbox jfreechart is blurry

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, jfreechart

I am trying to save jfreechart in pdf using PDFBOX.I am using PDImageXObject to save the chart as png and place it inside PDF using PDPageContentStream(PDFbox version :2.21.0). The problem is when it's saved as PNG it looks good but after adding those charts in PDF it becomes blurry.I tried using drawImage and drawXobject but still it's blurry.Kindly help me in getting good clarity charts in PDF.

Comment: Please include your code, the PNG file, the PDF file and update to the current PDF version (2.0.26).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_Improving quality of Buffered image in PDFbox_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72052145/230513).

Comment: I see it's the third time. You can edit a question to improve it. The comments here are to help you create a question clear enough for us to find out the best way to help you.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that reproduces you finding.